# Line and point collision in java

Tags: java, collision-detection, graphics2d

I'm making a tron game and have everything except for the collision. Currently making it through MVC (required as it is an AP Compsci project) and I am having trouble with the collision between the trail and the bike. My idea is to have a point on the racer to which it collides with (the front point). The light trails are drawn with a list of points, the first point being the start point and each point after are added when the racer turns. The last point is the current location of the bike. It draws a line between each point in paintComponent, and also uses a method in the Line class (which contains the arraylist of points) to check collision. So far I have tried to see if the front point is on any of the axis (that is, if the x or y value is equal to any of the corresponding x or y pvalues on the line) and then check the opposite coordinate and check if the x or y is in between the x or y of two points on that axis, and return true or false if they are. Here is what I mean:

```
public boolean checkPoint(Point p)
{

    for(int k = points.size() - 1; k > 0;k -= 2)
    {
        //if the x's are the same ( vertical ), check if within y's
        if(p.getX() == points.get(k).getX() && p.getX() == points.get(k - 1).getX())
        {
            if(points.get(k).getY() > points.get(k - 1).getY()){
                if(p.getY() < points.get(k).getY() && p.getY() > points.get(k-1).getY())
                    return true;
            }
            if(points.get(k).getY() < points.get(k - 1).getY()){
                if(p.getY() > points.get(k).getY() && p.getY() < points.get(k-1).getY())
                    return true;
            }

        }
        // if the y's are the same (horizontal), check if within x's
        if(p.getY() == points.get(k).getY() && p.getY() == points.get(k - 1).getY())
        {
            if(points.get(k).getX() > points.get(k - 1).getX()){
                if(p.getX() < points.get(k).getX() && p.getX() > points.get(k-1).getX())
                    return true;
            }
            if(points.get(k).getX() < points.get(k - 1).getX()){
                if(p.getX() > points.get(k).getX() && p.getX() < points.get(k-1).getX())
                    return true;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

The game either runs really slowly after a few seconds and works, or doesn't work at all. Am I going in the right direction, how should I go about this?

Comment: I haven't checked if your code is correct, but it sounds like if the game is running slowly, the problem is probably somewhere else. This isn't a very intensive operation.